# using foreach with a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I currently construct a multi-dim array from my input. like so: (example)

```
<form method=post action="testing.php">
<input name="response[0]['id']" type="hidden" value="<? echo $q1; ?>">
<input name="response[0]['answer']" type=text value=''>
<input name="response[1]['id']" type="hidden" value="<? echo $q2; ?>">
<input name="response[1]['answer']" type=text value=''>
<input name="response[2]['id']" type="hidden" value="<? echo $q3; ?>">
<input name="response[2]['answer']" type=text value=''>
<input name="response[3]['id']" type="hidden" value="<? echo $q4; ?>">
<input name="response[3]['answer']" type=text value=''>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

so that is successfully be POSTED. However I am trying to use a foreach to print out the values and I am getting it wrong.

**EDIT** my output array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array 
( 
['id'] => q1 
['answer'] => 1 
) 
[1] => Array 
( 
['id'] => q2 
['answer'] => 2 
) 
[2] => Array 
( 
['id'] => q3 
['answer'] => 3 
) 
[3] => Array 
( 
['id'] => q4 
['answer'] => 4 
)
)
```

can somebody explain how i would extract the values with a foreach or even a better way?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
Note the apos (`'`) are part of the name! Either change the HTML (`response[0][id]`) or do the following.

The incoming array should look like:

```
$response = array(
    0 => array("'id'" => ..., "'answer'" => ...),
    1 => array("'id'" => ..., "'answer'" => ...),
    2 => array("'id'" => ..., "'answer'" => ...),
    3 => array("'id'" => ..., "'answer'" => ...),
);
```

Thus,

```
foreach ($response as $resp) {
    print 'ID=' . $resp["'id'"] . ', answer=' . $resp["'answer'"];
}
```

---

**The problem:** `<input name="response[0]['answer']" />` will yield an array with `'answer'` as key. I.e., the literal string *with* apos, not just `answer`. You should probably change the HTML to `<input name="response[0][answer]" />` to avoid confusion. <strike>I will try and see if this is documented behavior.</strike> This behavior is indicated [in the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).

Comment: this is essentially what I tried and am getting no values out just the text.

Comment: @buymypies What does a [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) on `$_POST` (or `$_POST['response']`) give?

Comment: @buymypies You're very welcome. This was actually not just a look-in-the-manual question (which I first expected) :) Happy hacking.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($_POST['response'] as $response) {
  echo $response['id'];
  echo $response['answer'];
}
```

This should do it.

Comment: ive already set `$response` as `$_POST['response']` before the foreach.

Comment: No problem, its up to you, how you name your variables :)

Comment: Dont know, what you have tried exactly, but if you name your array `$response` you must use another name for the iterator variable, for examle `$entry`: `foreach($response as $entry) { echo $entry['id']; echo $response['answer']; }`

Comment: i simply implemented your example (so directly using the $_POST array) no luck.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're trying to do?

```
<?php foreach($response as $entry): ?>
    <input name="<?php echo $entry['id']; ?>" />
    <input name="<?php echo $entry['answer']; ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and ofcourse structure the inputs the way you would as above

Comment: each row has an `id` and an `answer`, So i want to get both for every row.

Comment: I spotted three mistakes in this example: you're not getting the value from $_POST, you foreach as `$entry` but use `$response` inside the loop and you spelled `$response` wrong.. ;)

Comment: im just going off the variables he's using.. who knows what framework he's using.. i dont use $_POST..

Comment: also his question is about extracting values of a 2 dimensional array which i am properly addressing. there's no errors.

Comment: if you look at my edit you can see the `print_r` output of my array after posting.